Does Hill-tribes followed Adi Shankaracharya?
I have seen in amar chitra katha book which give pictorial story of Adi Shankaracharya. In that book it is written that “ To find Srivigraha of Rishikesh mandir and talked with hill-tribes and made them as followers”

[][2
Is this story is authentic ?
